# Стилизация выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

возник вопрос по поводу стилизации списка option элементов
Имеется выпадающий список внутри которого 6 option элементов, при нажатии на каждый option элемент показывается разный контент

1)Как стилизовать option элементы(к примеру добавить расстояние между ними, либо при наведении на них закрашивать другим цветом итд)
2)И как сделать при открытии списка смену стрелок вниз-вверх?
3)Можно ли к каждому элементу списка добавить некий счетчик, который будет автоматических считать кол-во элементов внутри определенного option?

К примеру выбираем city1, у этого элемента внутри список из двух li и соответственно к city1 добавляется значение (2)(city1(2))

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#faq-questions').on('change', function(){
        var theVal = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('.answer').addClass('hidden');
     jQuery('.answer#answer' + theVal).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
 #faq-questions{    
position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.31;
    letter-spacing: normal;
     background-color: #fff; 
    padding: 40px 500px 40px 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    border-right: solid 3px #e9ebf1;
    border-left: solid 3px #e9ebf1;
    border-top: solid 3px #e9ebf1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e9ebf1;
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWZgRPvtxPhkB_GYREW6eQTHcviRWqiXnotyskuVkBICrWRWMX&s);
    background-size:5%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 93%;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;  
  }
  
  .hidden{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="option_box">
<div class="select_box_q"><select id="faq-questions" name="questions">
<option>Список</option>
<option value="1">city1</option>
<option value="2">city2</option>
<option value="3">city3</option>
<option value="4">city4</option>
<option value="5">city5</option>
<option value="6">city6</option>
</select>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer1">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 1 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer2">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 2 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer3">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 3 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer4">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 4 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer5">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 5 content</p>
</div>
<div class="answer hidden" id="answer6">
<p class="title_shops">Answer 6 content</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvd6e5uc/1/

Answer (score 2):

Стилизировать select в чистом виде весьма проблематично, т.к. можно использовать весьма ограниченное количество css стилей.

Если стоит задача сделать "красиво" - используйте один из множества jQuery плагинов, которые подменяют select на html DOM элемент (сохраняя при этом select и его интеграцию в код).

Например - https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Дальше вы сможете стилизировать все что вам требуется + получите дополнительный полезный фунционал вроде поиска по options, группировку, дополнительные callback фунции и так далее.

Конкретно ваш пример

Подключаем в шапке selectize через [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/selectize.js/)

```
<link <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" integrity="sha256-PaAZL3VjvuBsQSngzjA8dTdYa2mU88xmjd0vw8biXfg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-zwkv+PhVN/CSaFNLrcQ/1vQd3vviSPiOEDvu2GxYxQc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Если нет нужных для его работы плагинов - используйте standalone версию

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Правим код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faq-questions').selectize({
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text'
    }); /* Подключаем selectize */
    jQuery('#faq-questions').on('change', function(){
        var theVal = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('.answer').addClass('hidden');
        jQuery('.answer#answer' + theVal).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Меняем как хочется стили выпадающего меню и элементов:

```
.selectize-dropdown-content{
    background:red;
}
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/xaed9tbw/

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, у меня вопрос по selectsize, можно ли там отключить сортировку по алфавитному порядку? Либо закрепить один элемент option без контента на самое первое место, чтобы можно было свернуть форму

Comment: Да, конечно. Уберите из настроек плагина "sortField: 'text'". 

Если требуется использовать первый пустой option, то в настройках поствьте `allowEmptyOption:true`, тогда первый option заменит параметр placeholder.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/xaed9tbw/